# Button function does not work when in subpage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a function where i can download my table data into csv. But the button function only works when i place it in my index.html page, while my table's on the subpage.html page. But somehow, my button in the index page is able to download my table data in that subpage.html when i navigate to there.

Index.html : The button here works

```
      <body>
      <header ng-include="'views/header.html'"></header>
      <main ng-view></main>
      <button type="button" id="btnDownload"> Download as CSV</button>
      </body>
```

Subpage.html : If i place the button here it doesn't work

```
      <div>
          <table id="tabletodownload" ng-show="auditoriums === 'none'" style="border:1px solid #000;">

                  <tr> <th> Customer Name </th> <th> Order Value </th> <th> Ordered On </th> </tr>

                  <tr ng-repeat="audit in auditoriums| limitTo: 1 - auditoriums.length">
                    <td>{{audit.NAME}}</td>
                    <td>{{audit.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER}}</td>
                    <td>{{audit.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE}}</td>
                    <td>{{audit.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
                  </tr>

          </table>
          <br />
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="btnDownload"> Download as CSV</button>
```

Javascript code to DL to csv :

```
      $(function() {
       $('#btnDownload').click(function() {
               $("#tabletodownload").tableToCSV({
                   filename: 'CustomerList'
               });
           });
      });

      jQuery.fn.tableToCSV = function (options) {
          var settings = $.extend({
              filename: ""
          }, options);
          var clean_text = function (text) {
              text = $.trim(text.replace(/"/g, '""'));
              return '"' + text + '"';
          };
          $(this).each(function () {
              var table = $(this);
              var caption = settings.filename;
              var title = [];
              var rows = [];
              $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
                  var data = [];
                  $(this).find('th').each(function () {
                      var text = clean_text($(this).text());
                      title.push(text);
                  });
                  $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                      var text = clean_text($(this).text());
                      data.push(text);
                  });
                  data = data.join(",");
                  rows.push(data);
              });
              title = title.join(",");
              rows = rows.join("\n");
              var csv = title + rows;
              var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
              var download_link = document.createElement('a');
              download_link.href = uri;
              var ts = new Date().getTime();
              if (caption == "") {
                  download_link.download = ts + ".csv";
              } else {
                  download_link.download = caption + "-" + ts + ".csv";
              }
              document.body.appendChild(download_link);
              download_link.click();
              document.body.removeChild(download_link);
          });
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index.html and subpage.html are 2 different pages (and not an angularjs template or something like that) then it's probably because the code that is handling the button click and the rest of your function doesn't exist in the subpage.html.

**quick and dirty**

I assume you're not using any build tools. The simplest way is to move the button function to a script tag inside subpage.html

**the angularjs way**

I see you're using angularjs in the project. Manually attaching evenlisterens like a button click isn't the angularjs way of doing thing. You could easily move the functionality to your angular controller that control's that page and add a ng-click attribute to the button that calls that function. This way you're letting the framework decide when and hpw to attach the click event listener instead of managing that yourself.

Btw...
Using a framework like angular/react/vue most of the times makes jQuery unnecessary. In this case you could also use a library that made for amgularjs to make a csv from a table. jQuery is very *DOM* way of thinking while angular is more of a *DATA* way of thinking. In my opinion is that why it's better to not mix these things.

This might help you:
https://github.com/kollavarsham/ng-table-to-csv